# log sql statements inside stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

I would like to see the sql statements my stored procedure is executing, however I can only get the calling query to show up in the log.  Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION logtest(text) RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT 'you said: ' || $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
test=# set client_min_messages=LOG;
test=# set log_statement='all';
test=# select logtest('hello');
LOG:  statement: select logtest('hello');
     logtest     
-----------------
 you said: hello
(1 row)
```

But what I want to see is:

```
LOG:  statement: SELECT 'you said: ' || $1;
```

Comment: See [How to log DML statements executed by a pl/pgsql function?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71178/) on dba.SE

Comment: Yes, the auto_explain extension does the trick http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71316  However, it now logs everything including psql auto-completion; but definitely usable